# How long does Activation last?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm wanting to create a character who has to drink from an enchanted chalice at the start of each day, allowing them to access their powers for 24 hours. Would an Activation flaw cover this, or is that for more short-term power access (be it a scene, or an hour, or whatever)?

Answer (score 5):

### You should probably handle this with the Power Loss complication instead.

In general, if there's something you need to do outside of combat to keep your powers working, that would be the Power Loss complication.

> Power Loss: Certain circumstances cause some or all of your powers to fail or stop working, or rob you of them altogether. You might depend on particular objects others can steal or take from you, or lose your powers during the dark of the moon, or when exposed to exotic radiation. You may even simply lose faith in yourself, resulting in temporary weakness. When this happens, and poses a challenge for you, your complication comes into play.

If someone steals your magic cup, you lose your powers and take a Victory Point.

However, if you want drinking from your magic cup to be something you do in combat (e.g. because it turns you into a non-human alternate form), then it might be appropriate to use the Activation flaw for that power. One of the examples given of the Activation flaw was a guy with the power to turn himself into a rock-man, so that's a valid use of the flaw.

That said, there are several different durations for powers defined in the rules, and in general, they will last until you turn them off or are no longer capable of keeping them turned on.

Answer (score 2):

An Activated power lasts as long as its duration. A Concentration power will last as long as you spend the Standard action. Sustained as long as you spend the Free action. Continuous just maintains itself until cancelled through choice, Nullify, Counter, or something similar.

When you use Activation on a group of powers, you're essentially using it on [Enhanced Trait](https://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/enhanced-trait-general), which is Sustained. It's worth noting that Sustained powers are inherently Noticeable, so it can be told that you're doing something whether it's glowing with your ethereal power or your multi-barrel cybergun spinning up.